# Image with div as half background

Tags: html, css

Is there a way to use a blue bar behind the image like this?

[image]

This is what I'm doing:

```css
.line-divider{
    height: 125px;
    background-color: #29334B;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <div style="background-color: green; width: auto; height: auto;">
        <div class="line-divider" style="background-color: red;">           
            <img 
                src="https://dfstudio-d420.kxcdn.com/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2019/06/digital_camera_photo-1080x675.jpg"
                contain
                height="300px" 
            >
        </div>                   
    </div> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would simplify your code and consider only the image tag:

```css
img {
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
  border-image: linear-gradient(#0000 25%,#29334B 0 75%,#0000 0) fill 0//0 100vw;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://dfstudio-d420.kxcdn.com/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2019/06/digital_camera_photo-1080x675.jpg" height="300px">
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I would tackle this, apologise but I had to change the HTML and CSS.

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center; 
    align-items: center;     
    height: 100vh;
    background-color: #f4f4f4;
}

.container {
    width: 100vw; 
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center; 
    background-color: green; 
    position: relative;
}

.line-divider {
    height: 200px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    position: relative;
}

.line {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 5px;
    background-color: red;
    z-index: -1;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}

.line-divider img {
    height: 300px;
    box-shadow: 0 10px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    border-radius: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="line-divider"> 
        <div class="line"></div>          
        <img 
            src="https://dfstudio-d420.kxcdn.com/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2019/06/digital_camera_photo-1080x675.jpg"
        >
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple way to do it with Grid layout:

```css
article {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 50% 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 50% 1fr; 
}

div {
  background: #30353b;
  grid-area: 2 / 1 / 3 / 4;
}

img {
  grid-area: 1 / 2 / 4 / 3;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<article>
  <div></div>
  <img src="https://dfstudio-d420.kxcdn.com/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2019/06/digital_camera_photo-1080x675.jpg">
</article>
```